# Display thread execution on different output screens in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I have passed instance of a class in threads method. So the thread will basically run instance.start(). That is each thread will run a different class.

My goal is to have output of all the threads(or output of the classes running in thread) in different screens.

Can I do that? Is there any way?
Please help me achieve my goal

Comment: A simple solution would be to have each thread output to a different pipe or file, and then tail/cat a different pipe/file in different terminals.

Comment: By "different screens" do you mean different windows in a GUI application? If so, python has bindings to qt, wx, tkinter and other GUI toolkits.

Comment: Thanks Tom, Can you link me to some source that will help me do that?

Comment: tdelaney ... tkinter is very nice and easy